# How do I include two subsets into a function such as boxplot() or qqplot()?

Tags: r, subset, boxplot

I have two subsets I want to analyze,

```
subset(ClevelandHD1, presenceHD == "0", select=c(maxheartrate))
subset(ClevelandHD1, presenceHD == "1", select=c(maxheartrate))
```

but run into errors whenever I try and place them both into a function. What should I do?

Comment: How exactly do you try to place them both into a function? What exactly does that code look like and what errors do you get?

Comment: As it stands, your question does not have enough information to be answered.  It will likely get closed unless you improve it.  Please have a look at the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  If you can follow these good practices, you will no doubt recieve some high quality answers here.

Comment: I tried this function:

boxplot(subset(ClevelandHD1, presenceHD == "0", select=c(maxheartrate)) ~ 
(subset(ClevelandHD1, presenceHD == "1", select=c(maxheartrate))))

And was met with this error:

Error in stats::model.frame.default(formula = subset(ClevelandHD1, presenceHD == : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'subset(ClevelandHD1, presenceHD == "0", select = c(maxheartrate))'